# My python code output wrong html data

Tags: python, html, web-crawler

I have this code snippet  as part of python code to crawl a particular website (see the code below). But to my surprise the output code is not an html. I am using python 3.4

```
   import urllib.request as ur
   user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
   headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }

   s = ur.urlopen('http://www.nairaland.com')
   pl = s.read()
   print(pl)
```

My output from this code is:

**b''**

rather than the expected html code. Please guide me towards getting this code work. I need the html code in another part of the code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The excellent `requests` library returns the correct HTML:

```
import requests
s = requests.get('http://www.nairaland.com')
pl = s.text
print(pl)
```